# How to make HTTPS domain pull in the CSS data?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, cross-browser

I'm having some issues in IE8 where when I go to https://www.myapp.com, I get a security warning that says:

```
Security Warning: "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?"
```

It appears that my CSS files are getting blocked because when I choose "Yes", there's no styling.

I looked at my page source on my homepage as well as on the internal pages and this is what I found:

```
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/active_admin.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/comments.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How can I make it so that HTTPS renders in my CSS files without that security warning? I'm a beginner so even after looking in various files I wasn't sure where to find the data to change.

Also, I'm using the Bootstrap-sass ruby gem if anyone is familiar with that. In my CSS file, I have `@import "bootstrap";`

Comment: When I get that security warning, if I choose "Yes", the styling is all off. But if I choose "No" (meaning that all content is delivered securely as well as unsecurely), all of the styling is fine. This only happens in IE

Answer (score 4):

Use [protocol-relative links](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) of the following form for **external resources**. [They](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-scheme-relative-url) will ensure that those resources gets served over https when required. (For example, if linking in an external script-library)

```
//domain.com/external/resource
```

Also use the same path-relative-absolute style, to request resources within your css as well.

```
.elem{ background: url(/path/to/something.png); }
```

Comment: Sure, *if* the host is specified, but in this case where it not? That is, isn't a URL fragment without a host (i.e. `/path-absolute` or `path-relative`) a subset of a protocol-relative URL?

Comment: (I have only really seen protocol-relative URLs used for keeping the same protocol *across* domains, such as to a CDN resource.)

Comment: do you know how I can achieve this if I'm using the Ruby "bootstrap" gem? This is what I have in my custom.css file "@import "bootstrap";"

Comment: @pst is right. You don't need to change these urls, just the ones in your css, to use the same scheme. You need to go protocol relative *only* if you are pulling in resources from a different domain.

Comment: If I don't see any places to make URL changes in the CSS files, I should refer to another option right?

Comment: @johbones Can you ascertain which resources are failing to load? Check the script console.

Comment: It's mostly the "custom.css.scss" file which is inside my assets\stylesheets folder for my ruby on rails app

Answer (score 1):

Open your `CSS` files and look for any `absolute url` in there loading any image via `HTTP`. This happens when any element is loaded on an `HTTP URL`. Most probably your CSS files are including any background or any image from a complete url which is hardcoded as HTTP. Even the `jquery` source files if you have, have to be linked HTTPS